# How to check if variable exists in a print statement

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, decorator

So I have a function that contains a loop like so:

```
for k,v in dict1.items():
    try:
        if dict1[k] != dict2[k]:
           key_diff = k
           value_diff = dict1 [k]
    except:
        pass
```

If key_diff and value_diff are defined (i.e. there is a difference between the 2 dictionaries) then I want to print each of these variables elsewhere.  But the problem is I want to print it in a multi-line print statement like so (notice the last line)...

```
print("File extension count:",
    len(ext1_lst), '.ext1 files',
    len(ext2_lst), '.ext2 files', 
    'Missing File Types:', '\n',
    'Missing ext1 files =', ','.join(set(ext1_names).difference(ext1_lst)),
    'Missing ext2 files =', 'there is/are', value_diff, 'missing', key_diff, 'files', '\n\n\n',
```

The code won't work if the dictionaries are identical, since no dictionary is created--I get a "unboundlocalerror referenced before assignment."  My question is how can I check to see if there was a result to the try/except statement within the print statement.

Comment: Generally speaking, if there's ever any uncertainty as to whether a variable is defined, you're doing something wrong.  Initialize them before the loop: ``0`` and ``""`` would produce a reasonable output without further changes, or you could check one of the variables for its initial value, and omit that last line of output completely in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a try/catch inside the for loop. There is no condition where it would cause an exception.

Regardless, A simple solution would be to initialize the variables with an initial value before entering the loop. You can later compare to see if the values got changed.